# Information_schema.columns in the query

Tags: sql, join, schema, information-schema

I need to pull the data from custom columns in all tables which have "custom1, custom2, custom3....." columns.

```
Declare @TableName varchar(max)
set @TableName = 'RandomTable';

with main as 
(
     select distinct 
         infos.COLUMN_NAME, infos.TABLE_NAME
     from 
         INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS infos
     where 
         infos.TABLE_NAME = @TableName
         and infos.COLUMN_NAME like 'Custom%%'
)
```

This query returns the list of custom columns in any table I specify in the parameter. Any idea how to use that in the query so I can get all the data from the `RandomTable.Custom%%` columns?

Any idea? I'm loosing the plot on it.

Comment: You mean, if you would get three values (as in three columns), you want to get the values in these columns? And if so, do you wish to retrieve three separate columns or do you want all values to be returned in one column?

Comment: I would like to be able to specify in the parameter any table i want. If that table have 3 columns with the names of "Custom1", "Custom2", "Custom3" than i would like the values from those columns to be pulled in separate columns called "Custom1", "Custom2" and "Custom3". The same if the table have 10 "Custom" columns. Need to be some sort of dynamic.

Comment: This might not the cleanest solution, but perhaps you could do something like this...
Step 1: Create a temp-table. Step 2: Use the CTE as select statement for a cursor. Step 3: Inside the cursor, create a dynamic sql-statement (just a varchar variable that will result into sql-code) Step 4 (testing): Print the @SqlStatement to check if the query is proper sql. Step 5: Run the sql-code something like (EXEC @ SqlStatement) while the @ SqlStatement will inert data into the temp table when it's run. Step 6: Close the cursor. Step 7: Read the result from the TempTable

Answer (score 0):

Following incomudro idea and guessing you are using SQL Server you could do something like this:

```
DECLARE 
  @TableName VARCHAR(MAX)
 ,@ColumnName VARCHAR(MAX)
 ,@SQLQuery VARCHAR(MAX)
 ,@FirstFlag BIT
SET @TableName = 'TEST'

SELECT
  COL.COLUMN_NAME
INTO ##CUSTOM_COL
FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS COL
WHERE 1 = 1
 AND COLUMN_NAME LIKE 'CUSTOM__'
 AND TABLE_NAME = @TableName

DECLARE CUR_CUSTOM_COL CURSOR FOR
SELECT * FROM ##CUSTOM_COL

OPEN CUR_CUSTOM_COL  
FETCH NEXT FROM CUR_CUSTOM_COL INTO @ColumnName  

SET @FirstFlag = 1
SET @SQLQuery = 'SELECT *'

WHILE @@FETCH_STATUS = 0  
BEGIN
  IF @FirstFlag = 0
  BEGIN
    SET @SQLQuery = @SQLQuery + ', '
  END

  SET @SQLQuery = @SQLQuery + @ColumnName 

  SET @FirstFlag = 0
  FETCH NEXT FROM CUR_CUSTOM_COL INTO @ColumnName
END 

CLOSE CUR_CUSTOM_COL  
DEALLOCATE CUR_CUSTOM_COL

SET @SQLQuery = @SQLQuery + ' FROM ' + @TableName
EXEC(@SQLQuery)
```

I saved my workspace in this [fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!18/02c27/14/0). Unfortunaly it doesnt work there as intendet, but it should in your SQL Client(or I did a little typing mistake). With some little modifications you could not only display the custom columns from 1 specified table but from all tables. Also you could, besides selecting it, insert the ouput from the custom columns in temp tables.

Comment: I'm getting (0 rows affected)
Msg 156, Level 15, State 1, Line 1
Incorrect syntax near the keyword 'FROM'.

Comment: my bad, i missed the `*` in `SET @SQLQuery = 'SELECT *'`: The code should work now