# Script to create trigger from one table to another in MySQL

Tags: sql, mysql, stored-procedures

I have 2 schemas where 1st schema contains tables like TABLEA1 and 2nd schema contains the same table TABLEA2 with 2 additional audit columns.
I want to create a script which reads all the tables and its columns from information_Schema and for schema1 and creates the trigger on schema2 for each and every table.

```
CREATE TRIGGER AUDIT_UPDATE_old_table1 
AFTER UPDATE ON baseline 
FOR EACH ROW  
INSERT INTO Audit_tables.table1 (`AUDIT_STAMP`,`AUDIT_ACTION`,`id`, `created_at`, `created_by`, `created_by_login`, `updated_at`, `updated_by`, `updated_by_login`, `name`) 
VALUES (current_time, "K",id, old.created_at, old.created_by, old.created_by_login, old.updated_at, old.updated_by, old.updated_by_login, old.name);
```

Table names and column names should be read from information_schema as this information is not available to the script as input.

tried creating a procedure

Comment: You cannot. Such task needs in dynamic SQL (execute SQL code which is built programmatically). But CREATE TRIGGER is not allowed in dynamic SQL.

Comment: You can write code to create code run it then copy and paste the result and run that

Comment: @p-salmon can you please provide some example for the same. Creating code which can be executed as a separate step is fine for my use case.
found something similar for sql server

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52611154/information-schema-columns-in-the-query